# Unstable getting results from CiscoProvider.GetCall(int callLegID)

Tags: jtapi, cisco-jtapi

I have code:

```
        CiscoJtapiPeer peer = (CiscoJtapiPeer) JtapiPeerFactory.getJtapiPeer(null);
    CiscoProvider provider = (CiscoProvider) peer.getProvider(host+";login="+ login +";passwd=" + pass);
    provider.addObserver(new ProviderObserver() {
                    @Override
        public void providerChangedEvent (ProvEv [] eventList) {
            if (eventList == null) return;
            for (int i = 0; i < eventList.length; ++i) {
                if (eventList[i] instanceof ProvInServiceEv) {
                    inService.set();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    inService.waitTrue();
    System.out.println("In servise.");
        CiscoAddress srcAddr = (CiscoAddress) provider.getAddress(dn);
        srcAddr.addCallObserver(new MyCallControlCallObserver(dn, provider))
```

and observer on address:

```
        @Override
public void callChangedEvent(CallEv[] evlist)throws Exception{
    for (CallEv evlist1 : evlist) {

        if (evlist1.getID() == CiscoTermConnRecordingEndEv.ID) {
            call = provider.getCall(callid);
            if (call != null) {
                System.out.println("From: " + call.getCallingAddress() + "   To: " + call.getCalledAddress());
            }
            else {System.out.println("Call is null");}
        }
    }
}
```

function provider.getCall(callid) returns the object is not stable. Like this -

```
From: 4403   To: 5215 
Call is null
Call is null
From: 4403   To: 5215
From: 4403   To: 5215
Call is null
Call is null
From: 4403   To: 5215
```

The interval between calls 5 - 15 seconds and the duration of 3 - 7 seconds. I tried to change to handle the event - the same result.
What am i doing wrong? Maybe it's due to the fact that the CUCM is a cluster? And CiscoProvider is different for each call?

Comment: I tried to use two provider(on each node cluster) - the same result.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (evlist1.getID() == CiscoTermConnRecordingEndEv.ID) {
            call = provider.getCall(callid);
            if (call != null) {
                System.out.println("From: " + call.getCallingAddress() + "   To: " + call.getCalledAddress());
            }
            else {System.out.println("Call is null");}
        }
```

You are getting calls which has recording option true. You get only **RECORDED** calls. Thats why your function is not stable. If you want get all calls instead of **CiscoTermConnRecordingEndEv** use **TermConnActiveEv** if you want get call  in active state or **TermConnRingingEv** if you want get call in ringing state.